Exclamatory sentence: a sentence containing an exclamation or strong emphasis — so what does sarcasm and unethusiastic tone come under?
Oxford Dictionary says Exclamatory sentence: a sentence containing an exclamation or strong emphasis
So what does sarcasm and unethusiastic tone (and other weak emphasis) come under? e.g. "wow", "nice"  — Declarative sentence? Also, I'm under the impression that someone could say one of these words and it would make a complete (minor) sentence, is that correct? thanks

Note the conversation at https://english.stackexchange.com/q/626032/425655

No taxonomy is free of the problem of the square peg in a round hole.  Hammer "Nice"  into the Exclamatory category or the Declarative category according to whether it is a statement of fact or approbation.

Grammarians routinely identify four types of sentences: Declarative, which state that something happened or something exists. Interrogative, which ask a question. Imperative, which give an order. And exclamatory, which express surprise or amazement or emotion.
So for example, if I write, "Rover is a good dog", that is a declarative sentence. I am stating something. (It might be true or false, that doesn't change that it's declarative.) If I write, "Is Rover a good dog?", that's an interrogative. I'm asking a question. If I write, "Rover, be a good dog", that's an imperative. I am ordering someone to do something. If I write, "What a good dog!" that's exclamatory. I'm expressing wonder.
An exclamatory sentence does not have to have a verb. In my example, "What a good dog!", there is no verb.
Exclamatory sentences usually end with an exclamation. They are usually, but not always, said with emotion. For example, I might use an exclamatory sentence sarcastically. Like I saw a photo on the Internet of a "certificate of completion" from a dog training school, where they presumably teach dogs to behave ... and which the dog and chewed up and torn to pieces. One could imagine someone saying sarcastically, "Wow, what a good dog." Possibly in a totally flat tone of voice with no emotion.
Likewise, a declarative sentence might be said with great emotion. Like you might say, "My dog saved my life!" That's a declarative sentence but might be very emotional.
Point being, emotion is not the difference between a declarative sentence and an exclamatory sentence.
Sarcasm does not get its own sentence type. Any of the types of sentence could be sarcastic. "So you're a genius." "So, do you think you're a genius?" "Go be a genius somewhere else." "Genius!" Any of those could be said sarcastically.

what I'm finding puzzling is the "strong emphasis" part of oxfords definition — "wow", "nice" don't and I'm not sure "Wow, what a good dog." contains strong emphasis; I noticed you mentioned "emotion" a few times, is your understanding of a Exclamatory sentence mean it has to have either a exclamation point or emotion rather than ! or strong emphasis. thx

There are levels of emotion and emphasis. "Death to the infidels!" presumably carries some strong emotion and is an exclamatory sentence. But, "Nice putt, Bob!" is also an exclamatory sentence. Even though no lives are at stake, etc. I'm not sure what you mean by "an exclamation point ... rather than !" "!" is an exclamation point.

Is your understanding of what an exclamatory sentence is: a) It has to have an exclamation point or emotion; OR b) it has to have an exclamation point or strong emphasis?

Exclamatory sentences get defined two different ways, leading to this confusion.

Sentences that use an exclamation mark or have an "exclamatory purpose".
Sentences that do not have the standard structure of declarative, interrogative, or imperative sentences.

The first definition would include sentences that are also perfectly fine as other sentence types, if you removed the exclamation:

"I'm so happy right now!"
"Do you like it!?"
"Have a good night!"

In my view, this is a confusing definition. Unfortunately, it's also a common one. Various online sources insist that declarative sentences with exclamation marks are exclamatory:

Yourdictionary says "I hate you!" is exclamatory.
Study.com says "You're really funny!" is exclamatory.
Grammarly says "I got a perfect score on the SAT!" is exclamatory.
I can't find the OED's quote, but it sounds like they fall along these lines.

The second definition is that exclamatory sentences are a (somewhat outdated) category for sentences that don't fit ordinary sentence rules but are nonetheless considered proper English. For instance:

"Yikes!!"
"Happy birthday!"
"What a great day!"

are odd, grammatically speaking, since they don't contain a verb phrase. In this categorization, sarcastic phrases that follow the exclamatory structure (or perhaps just don't follow any other sentence structure) are exclamatory.

"What a... unique-looking... dog."
"Happy one-year-closer-to-death day."
"Woohoo."

The issue here is that if you don't require the exclamation mark, you might also include utterances like the "11:00" in:

"What time are we leaving?"
"11:00."

as exclamatory, so it's more common to classify these as types/usages of minor sentences or fragments, which are a less ambiguous category.
In general, if you're in a class, ask the teacher to clarify what they consider is the correct answer, and if you're learning on your own, understand that English grammar is often not a complete or entirely logical categorization.

If you don't mind me asking, where do you get that defintion of "Sentences that do not have the standard structure of declarative, interrogative, or imperative sentences." I cant seem to find anything other than having an exclamation point. thx
